# Can't remove card from Euchre hand in Python

Tags: python, list, playing-cards

I'm trying to program the card game Euchre in Python and I'm running into some errors with it. I'll post my code below and then explain my current problem:

```
import random

class Card(object):
    '''defines card class'''
    RANK=['9','10','J','Q','K','A']      #list of ranks & suits to make cards
    SUIT=['c','s','d','h']

    def __init__(self,rank,suit):
        self.rank=rank
        self.suit=suit

    def __str__(self):
        rep=self.rank+self.suit
        return rep
    #Next four definitions haven't been used yet. Goal was to use these
    #to define a numerical vaule to each card to determine which one wins the trick        
    def getSuit(self):
        return self.suit

    def value(self):
        v=Card.RANK.index(self.rank)
        return v

    def getValue(self):
        print(self.value)

    def changeValue(self,newValue):
        self.value=newValue
        return self.value

class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards=[]

    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
            rep=''
            for card in self.cards:
                rep+=str(card)+'\t'
        else:
            rep="EMPTY"
        return rep

    def clear(self):
        self.cards=[]

    def add(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def give(self,card,other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)

    def remove(self,card):
        self.cards.remove(card)

class Deck(Hand):
    def populate(self):
        for suit in Card.SUIT:
            for rank in Card.RANK:
                self.add(Card(rank,suit))

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def reshuffle(self):
        self.clear()
        self.populate()
        self.shuffle()

    def deal(self,hands,hand_size=1):
        for rounds in range(hand_size):
            for hand in hands:
                if self.cards:
                    top_card=self.cards[0]
                    self.give(top_card,hand)
                else:
                    print("Out of cards.")

#These two are the total scores of each team, they haven't been used yet
player_score=0
opponent_score=0

#These keep track of the number of tricks each team has won in a round
player_tricks=0
opponent_tricks=0

deck1=Deck()

#defines the hands of each player to have cards dealt to
player_hand=Hand()
partner_hand=Hand()
opp1_hand=Hand()
opp2_hand=Hand()
trump_card=Hand()      #This is displayed as the current trump that players bid on

played_cards=Hand()    #Not used yet. Was trying to have played cards removed from
                  #their current hand and placed into this one in an attempt to
                  #prevent  playing the same card more than once. Haven't had
                  #success with this yet
hands=[player_hand,opp1_hand,partner_hand,opp2_hand]

deck1.populate()
deck1.shuffle()
print("\nPrinting the deck: ")
print(deck1)
deck1.deal(hands,hand_size=5)
deck1.give(deck1.cards[0],trump_card)

def redeal():      #just to make redealing cards easier after each round
    player_hand.clear()
    partner_hand.clear()
    opp1_hand.clear()
    opp2_hand.clear()
    trump_card.clear()
    deck1.reshuffle()
    deck1.deal(hands,hand_size=5)
    deck1.give(deck1.cards[0],trump_card)

print("\nPrinting the current trump card: ")
print(trump_card)

while player_tricks+opponent_tricks<5:
#Converts players hand into a list that can have its elements removed
Player_hand=[str(player_hand.cards[0]),str(player_hand.cards[1]),str(player_hand.cards[2]),\
str(player_hand.cards[3]),str(player_hand.cards[4])]


print("\nYour hand: ")
print(Player_hand)

played_card=str(raw_input("What card will you play?: "))#converts input into a string
if played_card==Player_hand[0]:         #crudely trying to remove the selected card
    Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[0])  #from player's hand
if played_card==Player_hand[1]:
    Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[1])
if played_card==Player_hand[2]:
    Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[2])
if played_card==Player_hand[3]:
    Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[3])
if played_card==Player_hand[4]:         #received the 'list index out of range' error
    Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[4])  #here. Don't know why this is an error since
                                        #Player_hand has 5 elements in it.

opp1_card=opp1_hand.cards[0]  #just having a card chosen to see if the game works
                              #will fix later so that they select the best card
                              #to play


partner_card=partner_hand.cards[0]


opp2_card=opp2_hand.cards[0]


print("First opponent plays: ")
print(opp1_card)
print("Your partner plays: ")
print(partner_card)
print("Second opponent plays: ")
print(opp2_card)

trick_won=[0,1]   #Just used to randomly decide who wins trick to make sure score is
                  #kept correctly
Trick_won=random.choice(trick_won)
if Trick_won==0:
    print("\nYou win the trick!")
    player_tricks+=1
if Trick_won==1:
    print("\nOpponent wins the trick!")
    opponent_tricks+=1
if player_tricks>opponent_tricks:
print("\nYou win the round!")
if opponent_tricks>player_tricks:
print("\nOpponont wins the round!")

print("\nGOOD GAME") #Just to check that game breaks loop once someone wins the round
```

So far what I'm able to accomplish is have a deck created and each of the four players be dealt a five card hand and then have the player asked what card they would like to play. Once they play a card, the other three players (two opponents and a partner) play their cards and then I randomly decide who wins the "trick" just to see if the score is being kept correctly.

The current problem I'm trying to tackle is that once a player plays a card and the trick is played out, on the next trick they should have one less card in their hand when it's displayed but I'm not able to remove the card that was previously played so the player will still have five cards in their hand.

Do any of you know what I'm doing wrong and how I can have the selected card removed? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Instead of posting the code for the **entire game** and then asking about how to implement the next feature, try to boil the problem down to _how_ you have tried to implement said feature so we can debug it. This is just too big right now IMO.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was worried I wouldn't include enough code to be of help but looks like I went to the other extreme by accident. My issue is with the block of code that begins with "raw_input". My current attempt to remove the chosen card is listed in my code. Another method I tried was typing out "Player_hand.remove(played_card)" immediately after the raw_input prompt and not including any of the if conditions I currently have. My thought was that since I'd have played_card now defined, I could match it up with the correct piece in Player_hand and remove it but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The `IndexError` you're getting is because you're using multiple `if`s instead of `elif`.

```
if played_card==Player_hand[0]:
    Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[0])
# The next if is still evaluated, with the shortened Player_hand
if played_card==Player_hand[1]:
    Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[1])
```

use:

```
if played_card==Player_hand[0]:
    Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[0])
elif played_card==Player_hand[1]:
    Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[1])
```

But yeah, use those classes you made, and use `__eq__` to compare.

Comment: Also, checkout [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) sometime, worth the read.

Comment: My code still wouldn't remove the chosen card if I changed the next four "ifs" into "elifs" like you suggested. If I have Player_hand.remove(Player_hand[0]) or whatever other index on its own before the raw_input promt, I can remove that card without an issue. Just for some reason if I try to remove the specific card entered by the player, the program won't recognize anything to remove and they will still say I've got five cards in my hand.

Comment: Umm, yes it does? This is the error that your program hits, if you remove that `while` condition that will never be satisfied. You can verify this by printing the `Player_hand` list after removal.

Comment: Sorry about my confusion. I was removing the card from my hand but when the loop began again I was printing the original five card hand instead of the updated hand with the removed card. Thanks for the help.